# Creating a global variable inside a loop code block in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops

I am new to R and am trying to access data outside a loop

```
# List of 100 stock data
a <-c ("one", "two", "three", "four",...)
i = 1
while (i <= length(a)) {
  # make a list_element.csv to be accessed from local storage
  formated_path <-paste(a[i], ".csv")
    if (!file.exists(formated_path)) {
      output <- paste("Data for ", a[i], "Not found!")
      print(output)
    } else {
      print("found")     
      a[i] <- read.csv(formated_path, header = TRUE)

      # I have tried to change the name of the array to
      # correspond  to the element name but no luck as
      paste(a[i], "_stock") <-read.csv(formated_path, header = TRUE)
      return(a[i])
      i = i + 1
    }
  }
```

My desired outcome is to be able to use the individually loaded `.csv`s with other functions outside the loop. I do not desire a multidimensional array, just individual arrays corresponding to the array element as:

```
# Desired output
print(one)  # Should be the elements of a
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to load multiple `.csv` files? If so, there are much easier ways to do this in R. This answer is one of the easiest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40943207/3022126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to pursue your approach, the function you are looking for is called `assign`. However I would like to encourage you to think about your problem a bit differently:

```
a <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")
fileNames <- paste0(a, ".csv")
csvList <- lapply(fileNames, read.csv)
str(csvList)
```

Rather than the imperative approach from the question you can take advantage of Rs ability to work on vectors (`paste`) and functional programming (`lapply`).

If you need to further handle missing files, you can define a new `read.csv` function containing that logic:

```
myReadCsv <- function(fileName) {
  if (file.exists(fileName){
    read.csv(fileName)
  } else {
    message("File does not exist and is ignored")
    NULL
  }
}
```

And use it in the call to `lapply`. You can find detailed explanations in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-loop).